# quantile reg code in matlab

Tags: matlab, quantile

Here is my code

```
n=10000;
k=2;
v=(n-k);
Y=trnd(v);
x1=ones(n,1);
x2=randn(n,1);
X=[x1 x2];
u=randn(n,1);
Ols.Betahat=(X'*X)^(-1)X'*Y
```

But I got this error:

> The size of the matrix is not consistent. I attached an image of the statement

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have `n` data points in `X`, but your `Y` is just a number. Your `Y` should be a vector of length `n` (that is `n` rows and 1 column). So for every data point you'll have the appropriate target.

From the print screen, the role of `u_i` is not completely clear. 
If `u_i` is given as well (that is, if it's values are known to you), you should move it to the other side and define `Y` to be `Y-u`.

If on the other hand `u_i` represents an unknown error (which seems to be the case, as no information is given about it), then it does not participate in the OLS code.

So for the first scenario (known `u_i`) this would do the job (I replaced `n=10000` with `n=1000` because the latter is written in the print screen):

```
n=1000;
k=2;
v=(n-k);
u=randn(n,1);
Y=trnd(v,n,1)
Y=Y-u;
x1=ones(n,1);
x2=randn(n,1);
X=[x1 x2];
Ols.Betahat=(X'*X)^(-1)*X'*Y
```

If `u_i` is unknown, just remove it from the code and do the following:

```
n=1000;
k=2;
v=(n-k);
Y=trnd(v,n,1)
x1=ones(n,1);
x2=randn(n,1);
X=[x1 x2];
Ols.Betahat=(X'*X)^(-1)*X'*Y
```